# Implementation of the Treap Add function

Tags: java, treap

Hello so I am working on my treap method which requires a Stack to track the list of nodes that it goes through, and maintains the Heap Property by doing a list of rotations at the end. However, when I run this code it gives me nullPointerException() for my rotate methods. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is the link to both my node and Treap class.
[My Node and Treap Class Code](https://gist.github.com/xiaoyongiee/b1479460c434adc7a2d80cc1b8f46a84)

Comment: Looks like problem in line 101. You should use `rotateLeft` there

Comment: Please crate a [mre] and paste it into the question itself so that you will not need to keep the code from this question on GitHub indefinitely and so that it’s easier for a reader to get an overview.